# What's the difference between "Люблю идти по дороге" and "Люблю проходить по дороге"?

Tags: значения

Is there any difference in meaning between "Люблю идти по дороге" and "Люблю проходить по дороге"?

Comment: Can you maybe say in which context you have seen one of these phrases?

Comment: @Olga - I don't remember where I first came across "Люблю идти по дороге". I guess it was in one of the novels by either Тургенев or Толстой. It was exactly while I was trying to recall the source that it dawned on me that it might have been "Люблю **проходить** по дороге" instead, and that I didn't know the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the phrases:

```
Люблю идти по этой дороге по вечерам, ни о чём не думая.
Люблю проходить по этой дороге по вечерам, ни о чём не думая.
```

Here `идти` and `проходить` are in the same context.
I must admit that both phrases are possible and correct.

The first phrase is general use and does not need further explanation. (Yuri mentioned that it would sound even better with гулять or ходить, but we are talking about the difference of идти and проходить).

The second phrase can be perfect in some additional context. For example: `По вечерам на моем длинном пути с работы домой я люблю проходить по этой дороге, ни о чём не думая.`

Проходить is usually used when somebody/something goes through a layer, or gate, or some special place during a bigger-scale movement. For example:

```
Проходить через игольное ушко. 
Проходить по коридору. Проходить коридор.
Проходить по мосту. Проходить мост.
Проходить через тоннель.
Проходить мимо большой березы. Проходить большую березу.
Проходить этот уровень компьютерной игры.
```

Interesting fact is that the imperfect form (несовершенный вид) `проходить` corresponds to the perfect form (совершеный вид) `пройти` i.e. "про-идти". Maybe this was the original prompter for brilliant to ask the question. We can discuss what will be the difference between `пройти по этой дороге` and `проходить по этой дороге`. I think it is the implied repetitiveness of the action but it is not what the original question was asking about.

So, in conclusion, to my mind, проходить по дороге implies that the mentioned road (дорога) is a part of a bigger way before and/or after this road.

Comment: I think you've nailed it. Thanks. Switching "best answer" to yours, hope Olga does not take offense to that.

Comment: please, do correct this не о чём не думая. It hurts my eyes :) It should be нИ о чём не думая. And trust me, this correction is substantial.

Comment: Why should I? =)

Comment: @Milla: Thanks! This is what happens when one concentrates on the details - you do not see the bigger things :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you just wonder about the difference between verbs "идти" and "проходить", it is the following: "идти" means walking, and it often concerns some particular situation, not activity in general; "проходить" means the activity of passing through a place, or a landmark, either some particular situation or activity in general. If you want to refer to the activity of walking in general, you need to use the verb "ходить":

> Ты можешь идти? is appropriate if your friend has just fell down hurt his leg, and you are asking if he can walk
>   Ты можешь ходить? is good when your friend has had an operation after an accident, and you ask whether he will be able to walk again
>   Ты можешь здесь пройти? is when you are asking if someone can walk through a specific area.

As for the phrases, they both sound strange to me. A Russian would probably say "Я предпочитаю идти по этой дороге", or "По этой дороге я люблю идти", or "я люблю ходить по дорогам", "я люблю проходить по этой дороге". Or use some accentuation.

"люблю идти по дороге" sounds a little weird if you don't put any stress or if you stress "люблю". In this case, it means that you specifically enjoy the activity of walking on some specific road in a certain area, probably on a road that is in front of you right now. You like the walking itself, the feeling of your legs and feet moving. If you stress "по дороге", it means that you like going on the road (and, for instance, not across the field). If you stress "идти", it means that you like walking (and, for example, not driving) down a road.

"люблю проходить по дороге" is even more weird, because the verb suggests that you especially enjoy to walk down a road, because of a scenery, for example. But you don't specify which road it is that you like. If you say "люблю проходить по этой дороге", it would make infinitely more sense.

Comment: Didn't know that "люблю проходить по дороге" sounded weird. Okay, what if I change from **по дороге** to **по этой дороге** in both cases,  will then the difference between those two be still the same?

Comment: "я люблю идти по этой дороге" is still weird, "я люблю проходить по этой дороге" is much better, but both are possible. The latter means that you like to go down this road, you enjoy something along the road, scenery, memories... The former means that you like to go down the road and there is some specific part of the walking down this road that you like, but I cannot figure out what it could be.

Comment: What if I add even more of the context : "Люблю идти по этой дороге по вечерам, не о чём не думая" and "Люблю проходить по этой дороге по вечерам, не о чём не думая". Will that still be weird?

Comment: Olga helped a lot with removing some sounding weird from your original question. Now with your changes it is easier to comment. In "проходить" prefix "про-" is kind of equal to English preposition "through", so it emphasizes the transiency of the action: you passed through, maybe noticed something special on the go, and now you are in a different place. When you added more details to your phrase that describe the process of going, the phrase with "проходить" sounds little weird.

Comment: Olga's explanation is absolutely correct. Just wanted to note that “Я люблю гулять по этой дороге” and “Я люблю ходить по этой дороге” sound much better than “Я люблю идти/проходить по этой дороге” (“гулять” is better than “ходить”) and have a similar meaning.

Comment: I'd like to add, that "идти" denotes the action in general ('I like the process of going along a road, you never know what you see next.'), while "проходить" denotes a repeated action ('I like to go along this road, it has nice buildings, every time I go home, I choose this road.')

Comment: @YellowSky - "while "проходить" denotes a repeated action ('I like to go along this road ... every time I go home, I choose this road.')" - Are you sure that it's exactly "проходить" that denotes a repeated action and not the context? Look, if I change the context a bit, then "проходить" may well be referring to a one-time action: "Вчера он впервые в своей жизни прошёлся по этой дороге. Не понимаю, зачем ему вообще понадобилось вчера по этой дороге **проходить**"

Comment: @farfareast - "When you added more details to your phrase that describe the process of going, the phrase with "проходить" sounds little weird" - In fact, "Люблю проходить по дороге" doesn't sound weird to me at all. It's just that I didn't specify the context, but the phrase itself doesn't sound weird to me. If I had said something like "Люблю проходить в дорогам", then it would have been weird.

Comment: @brilliant I believe that you are right. It is the imperfective aspect that carries the meaning of repeated action. many other verbs have it, too. идти is a rare case when an imperfective verb cannot be used to denote a repeated action.

Comment: @brilliant - Irrespective of whether "проходить" can sometimes mean a one-time action, it is a _repetitive_ verb. _Идти_ is imperfective, _пройти_ is perfective, but any derivative of _ходить_ have the meaning of repeated action _per se_. There are only several Russian verbs that have this repetitive counterpart: бежать - бегать, везти - возить, вести - водить, гнать - гонять, ехать - ездить, идти - ходить, лететь - летать, нести - носить, and ползти - ползать.

Comment: @YellowSky - "...any derivative of ходить have the meaning of repeated action per se" - Allow me to disagree with you on this one. I still think the context is what matters here, not the verb pes se. Context is what controls the meaning of the verb. If you just rely on the verb per se and think likewise of all its derivatives, then you are at risk of making false conclusions. Look, none of the derivatives below imply a repeated action: 1) (игра в шашки) Твой ход. Ходи - Я уже **походил**; 2) Мама, я только что **сходил** по большому; 3) Ты Ромку не видел? - Видел. Он **заходил** ко мне утром.

Comment: @brilliant - It is the prefixes that add the perfective sense you mean. I agree with you that the context matters, but in other contexts all these verbs, even with prefixes, _can_ mean repeated actions: 1) Я **походил** по магазинам; 2) Я **сходил** с этой горки много раз; 3) Он часто **заходил** ко мне утром. Mind, that in your question you haven't specified the context, that is why **проходить по дороге** _can_ be understood as repeated action.

Comment: @YellowSky - "Mind, that in your question you haven't specified the context, that is why проходить по дороге can be understood as repeated action" - I don't want to sound stubborn, but there IS some context in my question. It is the words "люблю" and "по дороге" (if I had just asked "What's the difference between идти and проходить?", then you could say that the context was not specified), and I believe it is the word "люблю" that implies the repeated action behind the verb "проходить" in my question - if someone names something that he likes to do, it's understood that he does it many times.

Comment: @brilliant, and YellowSky please go to chat, your discussion is now too long to have it in comments. Here is a special room for you: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6760/discussion-between-yellowsky-and-brilliant

Comment: @brilliant Your phrase "Люблю проходить в дорогам" just cut me in pieces. :-) If seriously, we are talking here about subtleties, like looking in magnifying glass. On this scale it was sounding a little weird to me. I'm sorry if it sounded unfair.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: люблю ходить по дороге: люблю ходить по этой дороге на работу, т.к. она более зеленая.

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers on short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor and/or repetitive answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed.